# Multidimensional array for random.choice in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a table and I need to use random.choice for probability calculation, 
for example (taken from docs):

```
>>> aa_milne_arr = ['pooh', 'rabbit', 'piglet', 'Christopher']
>>> np.random.choice(aa_milne_arr, 5, p=[0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3])
array(['pooh', 'pooh', 'pooh', 'Christopher', 'piglet'],
      dtype='|S11')
```

If I have 3D array instead of aa_milne_arr, it doesn't let me proceed. I need to generate random things with the different probabilities for the 3 arrays, but the same for elements inside of them. For example,

```
>>> arr0 = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
>>> arr1 = ['light', 'wind', 'sky']
>>> arr3 = ['chicken', 'wolf', 'dog']
>>> p = [0.5, 0.1, 0.4]
```

And I want the same probs for elements in arr0 (0.5), arr1 (0.1) and arr3 (0.4) so as a result I will see with the probability of 0.5 any element from arr0 etc.

Is it any elegant way to do it?

Comment: That looks like `3` `1D` arrays rather than a `3D` array. Could you confirm?

Comment: Yes, thanks for corrections. Basically, what I want to have in the end is something like >>>np.random.choice([t, pos, n], 5, p=C1)

Answer (score 0):

Divide values of `p` by the lengths of arrays and then repeat by the same lengths.

Then choose from concatenated array with new probabilities

```
arr = [arr0, arr1, arr3]
lens = [len(a) for a in arr]
p = [.5, .1, .4]
new_arr = np.concatenate(arr)
new_p = np.repeat(np.divide(p, lens), lens)

np.random.choice(new_arr, p=new_p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came with.
It takes either a vector of probabilities, or a matrix where the weights are organized in columns. The weights will be normalized to sum to 1.

```
import numpy as np

def choice_vect(source,weights):
    # Draw N choices, each picked among K options
    # source: K x N ndarray
    # weights: K x N ndarray or K vector of probabilities
    weights = np.atleast_2d(weights)
    source = np.atleast_2d(source)
    N = source.shape[1]
    if weights.shape[0] == 1:
        weights = np.tile(weights.transpose(),(1,N))
    cum_weights = weights.cumsum(axis=0) / np.sum(weights,axis=0)
    unif_draws = np.random.rand(1,N)
    choices = (unif_draws < cum_weights)
    bool_indices = choices > np.vstack( (np.zeros((1,N),dtype='bool'),choices ))[0:-1,:]
    return source[bool_indices]
```

It avoids using loops and is like a vectorized version of random.choice.

You can then use it like that:

```
source = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
weights = [0.5, 0.4, 0.1]
choice_vect(source,weights)
>> array([3, 2])

weights = [[0.5,0.1],[0.4,0.4],[0.1,0.5]]
choice_vect(source,weights)
>> array([1, 4])
```